# Testing all possible features for regressions with scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, supervised-learning

Is there a way to test all possible combination of features to see which combination gives the highest coefficient strength for a set of features that I am interested in with scikit-learn?

For example, if there are 10 features, I want to test all possible combinations to see which set of features give the highest strength for three of the features that I am interested in.

I tried using the F regression built in function but it does not give an indication of which feature is actually useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but first we need to define the ***powerset*** of possible features. (This adapts the definition from the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), and assumes that we're interested in all sets of *at least two features*. e.g.: `(0, 1)`, `(0, 2)`, `(0, 3)`, ... `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`).

```py
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(2, len(s)+1))
```

Now we can iterate over every set in the powerset of features:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Create a demo set with 10 features and split into train/test
X, y = make_regression(n_features=10, n_informative=4)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

reg = LinearRegression()

best_features = None
best_score = -np.inf

# Iterate over all possible sets of variables
for c in powerset(range(X.shape[1])):

    reg.fit(X_train[:, c], y_train)

    # The "best" score is the one that maximizes the coefficient of determination
    if (score := reg.score(X_test[:, c], y_test)) > best_score:
        best_score = score
        best_features = c

print(f"Best set: {best_features}, best score: {best_score}")
```

And this gives results like:

```
Best set: (1, 3, 5, 9), best score: 1.0
```

**Caveats**: The size of the powerset grows proportional to `(2 ** N)`, where `N` is the number of features. `(2 ** 10) = 1024`, so it's possible to test all of them in this case. This method can also be sensitive to the split of the data, and the regressor used.

A heuristic approach built into `scikit-learn` is "Recursive Feature Elimination with cross validation" (see: [RFECV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html)), which tries to estimate how important each feature is using cross-validation, and incrementally removes features.