# Is it possible to provide a scoring metric to sklearn RFE?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, rfe

I need to get subsets of top 1, top 2, top 3, etc. features, and performance of my model on each of these subsets. Something like this:

| Number of features | Features | Performance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0.7 |
| 2 | A, D | 0.72 |
| 3 | A, D, B | 0.75 |

I wanted to use RFE as a possible improvement over simply using feature importances from models.

In sklearn, the RFECV object has a `ranking_` attribute, which would let me create the feature subsets. The problem is that all features below the number of features that RFECV found to be optimal are equal to 1, so the first `k` features are not ordered by importance.

I thought of using a simple RFE instead, but it doesn't accept the `scoring` parameter, and the default `accuracy` is not appropriate in my case where classes are very unbalanced.

Is there a way to either somehow provide a scoring metric to sklearn RFE, or to force RFECV (that does accept a `scoring` parameter) to evaluate ranking below the 'optimal' number of features?

I also considered using SFS but I have about 500 features and it takes days to run.

Comment: Since you seem to have working code, I think this question is more about ML than programming and would be better suited to another Stack Exchange site, like Cross Validated or Data Science, or maybe even to an `sklearn` discussion site.

Comment: @MattHall I was redirected here from Cross Validated

Comment: Lol, okay, that's too bad. My suspicion is that your best bet is to create a custom estimator with the `score()` method you want. It's not too hard to subclass the estimators in `sklearn`.

Comment: @MattHall that won't do anything; Charlie is incorrect that RFE uses accuracy to score feature sets.

Comment: The `rfecv.cv_results_` might be close. It's probably easier to enumerate the features if you need to find the best subset of fixed sizes. I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74833093/testing-all-possible-features-for-regressions-with-scikit-learn/74838014#74838014) that enumerated all possible feature sets, and it would not be difficult to constrain this to generate sets <= 3.